# df.drop_duplicates python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, drop

Running into some difficulty trying to drop correct duplicates from a dataframe.

I have the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


test = {'date': ['2012-10-12 10:10:10', '2012-10-12 10:10:10', '2012-10-19 10:55:10', 
        '2012-11-02 16:08:07', '2012-11-02 16:08:07', '2012-12-12 23:45:21', '2012-12-12 23:45:21'],
        'value' : [123, '', 324, '', '', '', 321],}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)
```

The output can be seen below:

```
                  date value
0  2012-10-12 10:10:10   123
1  2012-10-12 10:10:10      
2  2012-10-19 10:55:10   324
3  2012-11-02 16:08:07      
4  2012-11-02 16:08:07      
5  2012-12-12 23:45:21      
6  2012-12-12 23:45:21   321
```

My **desired** output after dropping duplicate dates is as shown below:

```
                  date value
0  2012-10-12 10:10:10   123
2  2012-10-19 10:55:10   324
3  2012-11-02 16:08:07      
6  2012-12-12 23:45:21   321
```

However, my attempts to date have been unsuccessful as shown below:

Attempt 1:-

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='date')

                  date value
0  2012-10-12 10:10:10   123
2  2012-10-19 10:55:10   324
3  2012-11-02 16:08:07      
5  2012-12-12 23:45:21
```

Attempt 2:-

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='date', keep='last')

                  date value
1  2012-10-12 10:10:10      
2  2012-10-19 10:55:10   324
4  2012-11-02 16:08:07      
6  2012-12-12 23:45:21   321
```

Please can you assist with helping me reach my **desired** output. Many thanks in advance

Comment: What is the "keep criteria"? I mean, which duplicates remain in the dataframe? the last occurrence? or is there something with value columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to mask the empty strings in the column `value`, then groupby on `date` and aggregate using `first`:

```
df['value'].mask(df['value'].eq('')).groupby(df['date']).first().fillna('').reset_index()
```

Alternatively you can mask the empty strings in the column `value` and assign it to temporary column `key`, then sort the dataframe on columns `date` and `key`, followed by `drop_duplicates`:

```
df['key'] = df['value'].mask(df['value'].eq(''))
df.sort_values(['date', 'key']).drop_duplicates('date').drop('key', 1)
```

Result:

```
                  date value
0  2012-10-12 10:10:10   123
1  2012-10-19 10:55:10   324
2  2012-11-02 16:08:07      
3  2012-12-12 23:45:21   321
```

Comment: the added benefit of having the index reset also, covers an issue I forgot to mention. Great stuff

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


test = {'date': ['2012-10-12 10:10:10', '2012-10-12 10:10:10', '2012-10-19 10:55:10', 
        '2012-11-02 16:08:07', '2012-11-02 16:08:07', '2012-12-12 23:45:21', '2012-12-12 23:45:21'],
        'value' : [123, np.nan, 324,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan, 321],}
```

This should work out!

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)
df.sort_values(by = "value", inplace = True)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='date')
df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
df.sort_index()
```

Output comes out like below:

```
        date    value
0   2012-10-12 10:10:10 123
2   2012-10-19 10:55:10 324
3   2012-11-02 16:08:07 
6   2012-12-12 23:45:21 321
```

Comment: thanks Srishti, however, the order seems to be skewed

Comment: Hey @windwalker, just added a sorting statement, to maintain the order, please check the edit, hope it helps!

Comment: the `df.sort_index()` makes it much cleaner now

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd


test = {'date': ['2012-10-12 10:10:10', '2012-10-12 10:10:10', '2012-10-19 10:55:10', 
        '2012-11-02 16:08:07', '2012-11-02 16:08:07', '2012-12-12 23:45:21', '2012-12-12 23:45:21'],
        'value' : [123, '', 324, '', '', '', 321],}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)

df["value_not_empty"] = df['value'].map(bool)
df = df.sort_values("value_not_empty")
df = df.drop(columns=["value_not_empty"])
df = df.drop_duplicates('date', keep='last')
df
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ismael, like  the @Srishti Garg solution,  the order seems to be skewed but I am grateful for all the help